# Why Row is not horizantally center inside a Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As we know by default,**Column horizontally** center its children if it has full width.But when i placed two cards and one row inside a column,two cards are placed horizontally center by flutter but **row remains same** at its start position? Why?
I think **row should be horizontally center** because it is a child of Column in my case but it's not.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          //  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Card(
              child: Text(
                'Chart',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              elevation: 5,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Card(
              child: Text(
                'list of tx',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('this is row'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv73w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because by default, Row will take the whole horizontal space. You can fix it by telling it to take as little space as possible:

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    ...
)
```

Setting the `mainAxisAlignment` of Row to `MainAxisAlignment.center` will  work only if there is one widget inside the Row. It only tells its children to go the center.

Answer (score 2):

By default `mainAxisSize` property is `MainAxisSize.max` in **Row** widget, What you have to do is just change it to `MainAxisSize.min`, To Affect by the parent widget, who in this example is the **Column**

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `mainAxisAlignment` argument to your Row . For example

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    ...
)
```

This will make children of the Row to be Centered.